# About worse case scenarios in binary searching

Tags: algorithm, search, time-complexity, binary-search

Binary searching's worse case scenario is `1 + lg n`, but does this worse case change if the element is in the sorted array or if the element isn't in it? I'm thinking that it should take less searches to decide that the element isn't in the array, or does the searching stay the same

Comment: There is a difference if you take the average case. But for worst case you explicitly look for the longest chain of comparisons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you have to make `k` comparisons in the worst case in order to check if the element is in the array. In the last (`kth`) comparison, if the key does not match, the element is obviously not in the array. So you don't need to make any more comparisons if the element is not in the array after the `kth` comparison.

Hence the worst case should stay the same irrespective of the element being in the sorted array or not, at `k=ceil(log(n))`.

Likewise, in the case of linear search, suppose the key would be in the last place in the array. We would need `n` comparisons, and if the last element of the array does not match the key, we can conclude that the element is not in the array. We don't need any more comparisons and the worst case will be the same (at `n`) irrespective of the element being present in the array or not.